# How to convert BuiltinString or BuiltinByteString to String?

Tags: plutus

Is there a way to convert `BuiltinString` or `BuiltinByteString` to `String` ?

There are these functions in the module `PlutusTx.Builtins.Class`

```
stringToBuiltinByteString :: String -> BuiltinByteString

stringToBuiltinString :: String -> BuiltinString
```

Are there functions to perform the inverse operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, per the [definition](https://staging.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-tx/html/PlutusTx-Prelude.html#t:BuiltinByteString), `BuiltinByteString` derives `Show`, so you can write `show bbs`, where `bbs` is your variable, and it will convert your `BuiltinByteString` into a `String`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!